# How to use Cookie for store jwt token user authentication?

Tags: reactjs, security, authentication, jwt, local-storage

I had done a Jwt token project with reactjs. So I use a local storage to log jwt token authentication for retrieve late.

I had log all work at the post: https://loizenai.com/reactjs-jwt-authentication-example/

But, my co-worker talk to me, it is not security to save jwt token in localstorage.
Have any recommnent for me why and give a right solution for the case!

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Server should generate a jwt token and return it as a cookie to your client:

const maxAge = 3 * 24 * 60 * 60; // 3days

return res.cookie('jwtToken', token, {
maxAge: maxAge * 1000,
httpOnly: true,
});

Client:

```
import Cookies from 'js-cookie';
import jwtDecode from 'jwt-decode';

 const authUser = () => {
    const token = Cookies.get('jwtToken');
    let isAuth;

    if (token) {
      const decodedToken = jwtDecode(token);
      if (decodedToken.id) isAuth = true;
      else isAuth = false;
    } else {
      // console.log('jwt cookie not available');
      isAuth = false;
    }
    return isAuth;
  };
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Is it a really good security for Web app when using cookie right?

Comment: https://stormpath.com/blog/where-to-store-your-jwts-cookies-vs-html5-web-storage